# Javascript Form Calculation

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, calculator

I Am trying to make a form in javascript that calculates mortgages and then renders the results onto the page.
This is my form:

```
<form name="calc" id="lidd_mc_form" class="lidd_mc_form" method="post">
<div class="lidd_mc_input mortgage lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive"><label for="lidd_mc_total_amount">Mortgage Required <note style="color: grey;">(omit commas)</note></label><input type="text" name="lidd_mc_total_amount" id="lidd_mc_total_amount" placeholder="£"><span id="lidd_mc_total_amount-error"></span></div><div class="lidd_mc_input down_payment lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive"><div style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"><label for="lidd_mc_down_payment">Down Payment</label><input type="text" name="lidd_mc_down_payment" id="lidd_mc_down_payment" placeholder="£"><span id="lidd_mc_down_payment-error"></span></div></div><div class="lidd_mc_input interest_rate lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive"><label for="lidd_mc_interest_rate">Interest Rate <note style="color: grey;">(enter 10% as 10)</note></label><input type="text" name="lidd_mc_interest_rate" id="lidd_mc_interest_rate" placeholder="%"><span id="lidd_mc_interest_rate-error"></span></div><div class="lidd_mc_input amortization_period lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive"><label for="lidd_mc_amortization_period">Repayment Period <note style="color: grey;">(omit commas)</note></label><input type="text" name="lidd_mc_amortization_period" id="lidd_mc_amortization_period" placeholder="years"><span id="lidd_mc_amortization_period-error"></span></div>
<input type="hidden" name="lidd_mc_payment_period" id="lidd_mc_payment_period" value="12"><div class="lidd_mc_input">

<input type="button" onclick="calc()" name="lidd_mc_submit" id="lidd_mc_submit" value="Calculate"></div></form>

<div id="lidd_mc_details" class="lidd_mc_details" style="display: none;"><div id="lidd_mc_results" class="lidd_mc_results"></div>
                <div id="lidd_mc_summary" class="lidd_mc_summary lidd_mc_summary_light" style="display: block;"></div>
            </div>
```

And this is the Javascript i am using:

```
            <script>
    function calc() {   /**  * Created by Connor on 13/04/2017.  */


        var mortgageRequired = document.forms["calc"]["lidd_mc_total_amount"].value;
        var interestRate = document.forms["calc"]["lidd_mc_interest_rate"].value;
        var repaymentPeriod = document.forms["calc"]["lidd_mc_amortization_period"].value;


//Calculation

//calculate repayment period in months
        var repaymentMonthly = repaymentPeriod * 12;

//Capital Payment
        var capitalPayment = mortgageRequired * (((interestRate / 12) * (1 + interestRate / 12) ^ repaymentMonthly) /
            ((1 + (interestRate / 12)) ^ repaymentMonthly - 1));

//Interest Only
        var noInterest = mortgageRequired / repaymentMonthly;
        var interestOnly = capitalPayment - noInterest;

//Display
        document.getElementById('lidd_mc_details').innerHTML +=
            interestOnly & capitalPayment;


 } </script>
```

The issue is that the page refreshes, and also simply doesnt work, as in it will not render anything to the page, even when the input is button over submit

I am also trying to make it so the code wont refresh the users page and will be asynchronous, is this the right way of doing so?

I am very new to JavaScript and would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Besides the page refresh issue, what problem are you having?

Comment: `"is this the right way of doing so?"` - Does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: Make sure you name your functions so you can actually call them.

Comment: Scott- Edited the question for clarity;
David - currently no, and I meant for good practice and standards so i could improve;
Jesse - The function is called calc is it not?;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is refreshing because you are using a `form` element with the `method` attribute configured. Forms are used to transmit data to a server resource, which is not what you are attempting to do here. In cases like this, you need to disable the form's submit functionality and you can do that by removing the `method` attribute.

Next, there is no HTML element called `note`. Those should be `span` elements.

Next, you are using an `&` at the end for concatenation. This should be a `+`.

Also, don't use inline HTML event handlers (onclick, onmouseover, etc.) as they create spaghetti code, cause implicit global wrapper functions that alter `this` binding to be created and don't follow the W3C Event Standard. Bind your event handlers in JavaScript using `addEventListener` instead.

Lastly, your results area is styled with CSS to be `display:none` so you don't see anything after clicking the button. You'll need to modify that after the button is clicked.

Here's a reworked version (see the comments):

```js
// These should not be in the function. You only need to scan the DOM for them once.

// Don't set your variables to the values of the input fields. Instead set them to the
// input fields themselves. That way, you can go back and get any other property of the
// field without having to scan the DOM for the element again.  Also, get the reference
// to the element using the more modern approach (i.e. document.getElementById()).
var mortgage = document.getElementById("lidd_mc_total_amount");
var interest = document.getElementById("lidd_mc_interest_rate");
var repayment = document.getElementById("lidd_mc_amortization_period");
var button = document.getElementById("lidd_mc_submit");
var output = document.getElementById('lidd_mc_details');

// Set up event handler for button
button.addEventListener("click", calc);

// The name of the function should not be in parenthesis.
function calc(){ 
  
  // Now, set up variables for the values and remember that all input element values are strings
  // by default and need conversion to numbers before math is done with them.
  var mortgageRequired = parseFloat(mortgage.value);
  var interestRate = parseFloat(interest.value) / 1200;    // Convert to decimal and get periodic rate
  var repaymentPeriod = parseFloat(repayment.value) * 12;  // Get period in months

  //Calculation

  //Capital Payment
  var capitalPayment = mortgageRequired * interestRate * 
                      (Math.pow(1 + interestRate, repaymentPeriod)) / 
                      (Math.pow(1 + interestRate, repaymentPeriod) - 1);

  //Display
  // Use textContent instead of innerHTML when the output doesn't contain HTML
  // and don't use & to concatenate in JavaScript as & means logical "AND", not concatenate
  output.style.display = "block";
  output.textContent = capitalPayment.toFixed(2);
 }
```

```html
<form name="calc" id="lidd_mc_form" class="lidd_mc_form">
  <div class="lidd_mc_input mortgage lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive">
    <label for="lidd_mc_total_amount">
      Mortgage Required <span style="color: grey;">(omit commas)</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="lidd_mc_total_amount" id="lidd_mc_total_amount" placeholder="£">
    <span id="lidd_mc_total_amount-error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="lidd_mc_input down_payment lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive">
    <div style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
      <label for="lidd_mc_down_payment">Down Payment</label>
      <input type="text" name="lidd_mc_down_payment" id="lidd_mc_down_payment" placeholder="£">
      <span id="lidd_mc_down_payment-error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lidd_mc_input interest_rate lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive">
    <label for="lidd_mc_interest_rate">
      Interest Rate <span style="color: grey;">(enter 10% as 10)</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="lidd_mc_interest_rate" id="lidd_mc_interest_rate" placeholder="%">
    <span id="lidd_mc_interest_rate-error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="lidd_mc_input amortization_period lidd_mc_input_light lidd_mc_input_responsive">
    <label for="lidd_mc_amortization_period">
      Repayment Period <span style="color: grey;">(omit commas)</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="lidd_mc_amortization_period" id="lidd_mc_amortization_period" placeholder="years">
    <span id="lidd_mc_amortization_period-error"></span>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="lidd_mc_payment_period" id="lidd_mc_payment_period" value="12">
  <div class="lidd_mc_input">
    <input type="button" name="lidd_mc_submit" id="lidd_mc_submit" value="Calculate">  </div>
</form>

<div id="lidd_mc_details" class="lidd_mc_details" style="display: none;">
  <div id="lidd_mc_results" class="lidd_mc_results"></div>
  <div id="lidd_mc_summary" class="lidd_mc_summary lidd_mc_summary_light" style="display: block;">   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im trying to use this solution @ http://www.liddleperrett.universalwebsitedesigncompany.co.uk/mortgage-calculator/ and it does not seem to work, any idea why?

Comment: "Does not seem to work." could mean anything. What does your developer console say? Have you placed the JavaScript in a `script` tag that is placed just before the closing `body` tag?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined caused by a function called changeSummary() which i didnt write, the website is based on the wordpress CMS

Comment: This is a completely different issue than your original post. There is no way to help you without diving into the `changeSummary()` function and debugging that.

Comment: Thats a very good point, I'll open a seperate question about that, ill mark your question as correct since its the solution i used and you have been the most patient with me :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a function to the form's submit event to stop the page from reloading. You can do this by using `addEventListner('submit', function(e) { .. });` on the form element. You'll use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form's submit event and you can continue with your calculation and output.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('calculator');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  // Prevent Default will stop the event from firing
  e.preventDefault();
  // Run your calculations here etc.
});
```

```html
<form method="post" id="calculator">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ge9a4vkj/) for an example.

Comment: You can also just remove the `method` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using form that uses what I assume to be a php method. This by default will refresh the page. You want to process everything without making any network request, so using DOM manipulation should do the job. Below is a working example.

```js
 function calc() {   /**  * Created by Connor on 13/04/2017.  */


        var mortgageRequired = document.getElementById("lidd_mc_total_amount").value;
        var interestRate = document.getElementById("lidd_mc_interest_rate").value;
        var repaymentPeriod = document.getElementById("lidd_mc_amortization_period").value;


//Calculation

//calculate repayment period in months
        var repaymentMonthly = repaymentPeriod * 12;

//Capital Payment
        var capitalPayment = mortgageRequired * (((interestRate / 12) * (1 + interestRate / 12) ^ repaymentMonthly) /
            ((1 + (interestRate / 12)) ^ repaymentMonthly - 1));

//Interest Only
        var noInterest = mortgageRequired / repaymentMonthly;
        var interestOnly = capitalPayment - noInterest;

//Display
        document.getElementById('lidd_mc_details').innerHTML +=
            interestOnly & capitalPayment;


 }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  lidd_mc_total_amount
  <input type="text" id="lidd_mc_total_amount"/>
  <br>
  lidd_mc_interest_rate
  <input type="text" id="lidd_mc_interest_rate"/>
  <br>
  lidd_mc_amortization_period
  <input type="text" id="lidd_mc_amortization_period"/>
  <br>
  <button onClick="calc()">Click for answer</button>

  <div>The answer: <span id="lidd_mc_details"></span></div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Form elements should always be wrapped within a `form` element. Simple removal of the `method` attribute will solve the refresh issue.

Comment: Works great in the fiddle, but on my site returns a "Uncaught ReferenceError: calc is not defined" any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that the function is defined at the bottom at the page, near the closing end of the `body` tag or at the very least after the HTML markup that uses the function calc.